# Making a search form display inline with Bootstrap 5

Tags: forms, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a search form within a page using Bootstrap 5 and the following code:

```
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <label for="field">Find all where...</label>
                    <select id="field" class="form-select">
                        <option value="company_name" selected>Company Name</option>
                        <option value="federal_ein" selected>EIN</option>
                        <option value="state">State</option>
                        <option value="city">City</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="term">includes...</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="term" placeholder="Enter full/partial term" name="term">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want the form to be inline, with the text box stretched to fill unused space in the row.  I can't figure out how to achieve this.  Any help on it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work well.  Thanks!

```
<form id="frmSearch" name="frmSearch" role="form" class="was-validated">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-1 text-end">Find companies where...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 text-start">
                    <select ID="ddlType" Class="form-control rounded" required>
                        <option value="" selected>Search by...</option>
                        <option value="company_name">Company Name</option>
                        <option value="city">City</option>
                        <option value="federal_ein">EIN</option>
                        <option value="state">State</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">contains...</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex">
                    <input type="text" ID="tbTerm" class="form-control rounded text-black" required />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 mx-auto">
                    <button type="submit" ID="btnSearch" class="btn-success btn text-white">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```